# ZFS on >2TB disk in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, gpt

I just got a 4TB disk and I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/2tb-gtp-parted/ says you need to partition your disk with GPT if you want to use >2TB (and that you can do this with fdisk/gparted).

However I'm interested in using ZFS.  When I tried just running `zpool create tank /dev/sde`, I end up with 2TB:

```
$ sudo zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  1.81T   576K  1.81T     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

$ sudo parted /dev/sde print
Model: WD My Book 1140 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      8389kB  2000GB  2000GB               zfs
 9      2000GB  2000GB  67.1MB
```

How should I proceed?  Thanks for any hints.

Comment: @Zoredache From `man fdisk` from util-linux 2.20.1: *"**fdisk does not understand GUID partition tables (GPTs)** and it is not designed for large partitions. In these cases, use the more advanced GNU parted(8)."* However, the OP did use full device for the vdev, so the capabilities of fdisk *shouldn't* be an issue.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling my mistake.  I skimmed the first paragraph and saw 4tb and fdisk.

Comment: @Yang Looking at the output, are you *absolutely positive* that you did receive a 4 TB drive? Because it does look like you are dealing with a 2 TB drive, in which case the behavior you are seeing is perfectly explainable. (ZFS and Parted agree on a 2 TB drive size.) Check `sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sde`; that'll report what size the system sees the drive as, in bytes.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Well, unless I got scammed by Fry's, yeah it's a WD 4TB drive. I heard the 2TB capping is what HPA does. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/330666/zfs-on-2tb-disk-in-ubuntu-12-04/330729?noredirect=1#330729